# With ruamel.yaml how can I push the dash inwards but not when they are at the top level

Tags: python, yaml, ruamel.yaml

With `yaml.indent(mapping=2, sequence=2, offset=0)` (the defaults) 
The dash at top level are not pushed inwards, like all other dash

```
import sys
import ruamel.yaml

yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
yaml.indent(mapping=2, sequence=2, offset=0)
inp = """\
- op: replace
  path: /x/y/z
  value:
    - name: dummy
      property: fake

- op: replace
  path: /a/b/c
  value: roger
"""

data = yaml.load(inp)

yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)
```

Result:

```
- op: replace
  path: /x/y/z
  value:
  - name: dummy
    property: fake

- op: replace
  path: /a/b/c
  value: roger
```

With `yaml.indent(mapping=2, sequence=4, offset=2)`, all the dash are pushed inwards, including those at the first level

```
import sys
import ruamel.yaml

yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
yaml.indent(mapping=2, sequence=4, offset=2)
inp = """\
- op: replace
  path: /x/y/z
  value:
    - name: dummy
      property: fake

- op: replace
  path: /a/b/c
  value: roger"""

data = yaml.load(inp)

yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)
```

Result:

```
  - op: replace
    path: /x/y/z
    value:
      - name: dummy
        property: fake

  - op: replace
    path: /a/b/c
    value: roger
```

Is there a way to produce this result? :

```
- op: replace
  path: /x/y/z
  value:
    - name: dummy
      property: fake

- op: replace
  path: /a/b/c
  value: roger
```